# Search through Array from Data Model in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swiftui, ios14

**Another tricky SwiftUI problem I cannot solve!**

I have 2 lists in a view, each one is reading from a Data Model struct. When a row is selected in the first list I am updating a `@State` with the title of the row selected.

In my second list the data model has an array that may or may not match the title of the updated `@State`. I am trying to search through the array to see if it matches the newly selected `@State` string and only present the row if it matches, but I cannot work out how to search through each array for each row. How do I access the array to see if it matches `@State`?

I haven't included the 2 row views `ApplicationsListRow` and `ProductListRow` as these are simple HStacks that just source the title from the data model.

Here is my view with the 2 list:

```
struct ProductListTabApplications: View {
    
    @State private var selectedOption = "Food"
    
    var applications: [ApplicationModel] = applicationData
    var products: [ProductModel] = productData
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            List(){
                ForEach(applications) { item in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.selectedOption = item.title
                    }) {
                        ApplicationsListRow(application: item)
                    }
                }
            }
            List{
                ForEach(products) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ProductTabView(product: item)) {
                        ProductListRow(product: item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried having for loops and if statements in the second list but I cannot work out a way to access the the array to see if it exists. Here is one of the examples I tried:

```
ForEach(products) { item in
     ForEach(item) { application in
         if item.application[application] == selectedOption {
            // list items
          }
      }
 }
```

Simplified data model:

```
struct ProductModel: Identifiable {
var id = UUID()
var title: String
var application: [String]  
}
```

Simplified struct:

```
let productData: [ProductModel] = [
    ProductModel(
        title: "product1",
        application: ["Food","Metals","Beverage"]
    ),
    ProductModel(
        title: "product2",
        application: ["Beverage"]
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`filter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) to find matches in your lists.

example:

```
let matchedItems = products.filter {
    product in
    let list = product.application
    for item in list {
        if item == selectedOption {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

now you have all products that have a matched string in their application array.